# How to refresh a ChoiceBox in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I would like to refresh the choice box after I added a new value it should be shown there.

I read all the topics about this that I found on stackoverflow but none of these worked.

```
public void setNamesChoiceBoxes() {
    ArrayList<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    workers = db.getWorkers();

    for (Worker i : workers) {
        String tmp = i.getName() + " (" + i.getID() + ")";
        names.add(tmp);
    }

    ArrayList<String> searchNames = new ArrayList<>(names);
    searchNames.add(0, "All");
    ObservableList<String> search = FXCollections.observableList(searchNames);
    searchNameChoiceBox.setItems(search);
    searchNameChoiceBox.setValue(search.get(0));


    ArrayList<String> addNames = new ArrayList<>(names);
    addNames.add(0, "");
    ObservableList<String> add = FXCollections.observableList(addNames);
    addNameChoiceBox.setItems(add);
    addNameChoiceBox.setValue(add.get(0));
}

@Override
public ArrayList<Worker> getWorkers() {
    ArrayList<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select * from names";

    try {
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            workers.add(new Worker(id, name));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception in class \"DB\" (\" public ArrayList<Worker> getWorkers()\" failed): " + ex);
    }
    return workers;
}

@FXML
public void addNewWorkerButton(ActionEvent event) {
    String name = workerNameTextField.getText();
    workerNameTextField.setText("");
    db.addWorker(name);
    addWorkerAnchorPane.setVisible(false);
    mainAnchorPane.setOpacity(1);
    mainAnchorPane.setDisable(false);

    setNamesChoiceBoxes();
}
```

I get the worker names from the database when I start the program, it works perfectly. When I add a new name to the DB, and call the "setNamesChoiceBoxes" method (to refresh the choicebox from DB), it gives alot of errors, although the new name is in the Choice Box list, but the "searchNameChoiceBox" value should be "All" but it is "".

After I added a new name choice box looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2HaX.jpg

It should be like this... (since I set the value to "All" in method...): https://i.stack.imgur.com/i66vv.jpg

Comment: A lot of info about the implementation of methods is missing. However the question seems to come down to: Why does `searchNameChoiceBox.setItems(search); searchNameChoiceBox.setValue(search.get(0));` not select the first value in the list which is something I cannot reproduce. BTW: the implementation of `setNamesChoiceBoxes` is odd, but not necessarily wrong: The initial value of `workers` is dropped without using it. For some reason copy a list that is never used again to a new `ArrayList` even though modifying the original list would do the trick.

Comment: Also inserting a new item at the start of an `ArrayList` after adding all other elements is inefficient, since this requires moving all items in the array used to store them. Simply adding the item first and then all of the other items would avoid this.

Comment: "BTW: the implementation of setNamesChoiceBoxes is odd, but not necessarily wrong: The initial value of workers is dropped without using it." - this is because there is an another ChoiceBox aswell: "addChoiceBox" where you have to choose a worker, "All" would not be an option. But if I use the same ArrayList, both the "" (where is no chosen option) and "All" would be in the list. What would be wrong. I change the original post and copy-paste the whole code.

Comment: But yeah, as you said: the question is why that 2 line is not working if I call it again?... Why it gives alot of errors...

Comment: Errors: https://pastebin.com/YNHsWscs

Comment: You can/should include important info to the question by [edit]ing it. However the linked error will not improve the question, since the issue happend in code that you did not post. Did you perhaps add an erroneous listener to the `value` property (or some similar property of the selection model) or an `onAction` event handler perhaps?

Comment: Can you tell me exactly, which method/function I should post?

Comment: Not sure how exactly you put together the pieces resulting in the issue come together, but I'm but you need to provide a [mcve]. I'm pretty sure your `ChoiceBox` cannot deal with the fact (see topmost code line mentioned in the stacktrace posted) that refreshing the items temporarily resets the value back to `null`...

Answer (score 0):

I think i understood that you want a particular item to be selected and shown in your ChoiceBox?

If so, I would  recommend to remove this line(and analoguous for the other Box):

```
 //addNameChoiceBox.setValue(add.get(0));
```

And use instead a real selection for the Item to show. This selects the first Item:

```
addNameChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);
```

Alternativly there is a seperate method that also selects the first Item:

```
addNameChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
```

And then again you may want to select the Item shown by value:

```
addNameChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().select("All"); //or whatever value you want to select.
```

I hope this helps you at least with a part of your problem.

Comment: addNameChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst(); - I tried only this but it is working perfectly. Thank you. Did not know there is such a command like this.

Comment: Maybe you want to use FXCollections.observableArrayList(...) instead of FXCollections.observableList(...). This might add litle more robustness too(lesser possibillities for errors).